# Can't get minecraft PE invites on my windows 10 edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I have both windows 10 and PE of Minecraft but when my cousin invites me, I only get the invite on my phone on the PE edition of Minecraft and not on my windows 10 edition. I'm pretty sure that both of them are connected to my Xbox account and both of them are connected to the same WiFi network too..

When I turn off net on my phone, I still don't get the invite on my PC version..

Both versions are up to date..so I really don't know whats going on here...can someone please help me? This problem started occurring some time ago..

Comment: What version is your cousin playing?

Comment: im on the latest version and I can play with her on my mobile so doesn't that mean she has the same version?

Comment: I should have been clearer - is your cousin playing on Windows 10 or PE?

Comment: she is playing on pc, its like this- me, my sister live in the same house and 2 cousins live in a different city. My sis plays on PE, I sometimes play on windows 10 or on PE, the one sending the invite plays on windows 10 and her sis plays on PE. We all play together in the same world but I cant seem to get an invite on windows 10, I can only get it on PE..

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling PE from your phone?

Comment: why would i do that?

Comment: To see if the invite is then sent to your PC

Comment: ok i will try it!

Comment: this is weird..I deleted it from my phone, still didnt get invite on pc. Then I redownloaded it on pc, no invite yet again. She says she sees me offlime when she is on pc but online from phone. Same happens for me, I see her offline on my pc while she is playing..

Answer (score 1):

They are incompatible. I had to look this up myself when my children wanted to all play on windows, Xbox and PE. The PE version is fundamentally a different version from the rest of them. Sorry.

Comment: but i did get them a while back..they ARE the same game

Comment: My apologies. I'm going to have to look into this for my kids.aparently as of version 0.12.1. All that’s required is that each device is on the same local network.

To start, one of the players has to enter a new world or one of their existing worlds. Then everyone else can join in. On Android and iOS, once someone on the same network is in a world, others can click Play and the local world should show up as an option. It may take a few seconds before you see it, but you can see which ones are local worlds since there will be a local IP address associated with it. (This is from a quick Google)